# How do you sort an array based on value

Tags: php

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(100) [2]=> int(6) }
```

I want to sort the following array in numerical order max - min.

Expected output:

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(100) [1]=> int(6) [2]=> int(1) }
```

However, when I use `asort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC)` or `sort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC)` I get this unexpected result:

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(6) [1]=> int(100) [2]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: not reproducible, works for me... http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8b430e79a1c9e837980f607b81a0002ba355e6f

Answer (score -1):

PHP [`sort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) has `SORT_NATURAL` flag.

It should be...

```php
sort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
// or
rsort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
```

Tests:

```php
$array = [1, 100, 6];

sort($array, SORT_NATURAL);

var_dump($array);

rsort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
var_dump($array);
```

> array (size=3)   0 => int 1   1 => int 6   2 => int 100
>
> array (size=3)   0 => int 100   1 => int 6   2 => int 1